# Отображение vue в исходном коде

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не так давно изучаю vue и столкнулся с такой проблемой: в исходном коде (а соответственно так видит и робот поисковых систем) у меня вместо контента отображаются мои переменные vue

```
    <h1>@{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="content">@{{content}}</div>
```

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как правили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как бы это у всех так. Есть решение - серверный рендеринг 'Vue SSR'. Введите в поиске и посмотрите. Но гуголбот, как я думаю, и так нормально рендерит страницу для индексации.